# Will #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored be applied only per compilation unit?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings

Can't find any concrete documentation about GCC.

Question is: if I set (for example) a `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "{some-diag}"` on a .cpp file, will this be applied only after this statement for the whole compilation unit?

Or it will be enable by default after the first execution and applied for all the next compilation (over different compilation unit)?

Same question fo the header: if a .hpp contains `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "{some-diag}"`, once enabled, it will applied to other compilation unit, even if that header will not be included on them?

Comment: It will be local to a source file, so it will be "active" from the moment it occurs until the end of the current file.

Comment: @PepijnKramer edited the question. What about header that are not included in other comp unit but enable that ignore statement?

Comment: AFAIK it will still be local to apply only ot warnings in that header file. But imo best practice is to use it in combination with #pragma diagnostics push (and pop) to really keep the ignore as local as can be. And only to do it for 3rd party errors. Those warnings usually exist for a reason.